# How do I send a Variable into Python from Javascript

Tags: javascript, python

This is a simple straight forward question. The code with the JSONP Python callback works (the ?callback=? part). It gets the callback parameter from the Python script on the server.

How do I add a JavaScript variable (varExample) into the data.py line alongside callback=? without breaking the callback. Thanks.

```
var jsonp_url = "https://example.com/cgi-bin/data.py?callback=?";       
$.getJSON(jsonp_url, function(data) {
$('#widget').html(data.html);
});
```

Comment: Do you know how to build a query string? you can separate parameters with `&` like `'...data.py?example=' + varExample + '&callback=?'`. You'll have to make sure your `data.py` script parses them out in order to use them. There are Python libraries that can help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

**This works on the JavaScript File Side**

```
var jsonp_url = "https://example.com/cgi-bin/data.py?varExampleForPython=" + 
varExample + "&callback=?";
```

**Retreiving varExamplePython in the Python (.py) File Side**

```
retrievedVarExample = params['varExampleForPython'].value
```